# Iterate through user custom fields in twig

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I'm trying to iterate through a user reference field using twig. I'm able to get the username, but not any of the custom fields that I made for users such as "First Name" and "Last Name".

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ kint(item.content['#options']) }}
  {{ item.content['#title'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to get the email address as well, but I can't figure out how to get these values.

[image]

I thought it would be something like:

```
{{ item.content['#options'].entity.mail }}
```

When I do that, the entire site crashes and I get errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You shouldn’t be trying to pick apart the items like that in a field template, just let them render. You’ve got a reference field, so setup the view mode it’s pointing at to render it, start there.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. I had copied that from the block template that I was working on. So now I'm just using {{ content }}. Still can't access the custom fields though.

Answer (score 2):

You should never try to display field values by going that deep into structured field properties data within your Twig templates.

Consider using according field displays, or [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK) to preprocess your template variables, e.g. by providing a simple array of preprocessed item data the template can iterate over (an abstract example to put into your mytheme.theme file; where you have to replace `mytheme` with the name of your theme and `themehook` with the template's theme registry hook - usually the template name with underscores instead of dashes):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_themehook(&$variables) {
  // This will be the new list variable to attach to the
  // template.
  $users_list = [];

  // Get the entity object from existing theme variables.
  // This example assumes you have a node entity in
  // your variables array already.
  $entity = $variables['#node'];

  // Load all referenced users from a field named
  // 'field_users_entityreference'.
  $users = $entity->get('field_users_entityreference')->referencedEntities();

  // Iterate through all users found.
  if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach($users as $user) {
      $item = [
        // Add whichever properties you'd like
        // to show within your template.
        'email' => $user->getEmail(),
      ];
      $users_list[] = $item;
    }
  }

  // Attach the new variable to the template.
  $variables['users_list'] = $users_list;
}
```

In your Twig template you can now access the users list by accessing the new `users_list` variable:

```
{% if users_list %}
  {% for item in users_list %}
    {{ item.email }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

EDIT:

According to the template name you provided, you are trying to alter how the entity reference field itself is displayed. Generally you have the following choices:

(1) Using field display: Add an according display to the user entity and change the field display to rendered Entity using this display. You can do so by

- Go to "Admin / Structure / Display modes / View modes".
- Find the User entity (should be somewhere at the bottom) and add a new user view mode.
- Then go to "Admin / Configuration / People / Account settings / Manage display".
- Choose the newly created view mode and add all fields you want to show.
- Within "Admin / Structure", head to the entity using the reference field and find the "Manage display" tab.
- At the field in question change the Format to rendered entity and choose your newly created display mode by clicking the cogwheel at the very right of the row.

This approach usually fits your needs if you don't want to digg too deep into programming. Unfortunately you'd like to show the email address. This field is usually not available in user displays (privacy reasons; re-consider if you really want to show it). If you like to add that field to a regular user view, you'd have to additionally implement [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view).

(2) Alter the additional template variables within a preprocessing hook:

- Within "Admin / Structure", head to the entity using the reference field and find the "Manage display" tab.
- At the field in question change the Format to Entity ID.
- Implement a preprocessing hook as described above.
- Fetch the item IDs from the existing variables and load the user entities.
- Attach your information to the variables and use it within your template:

  $users = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::loadMultiple($variables['items']);

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still trying to figure out how to make these theme hooks and how twig is used with that. Odd that twig is supposed to be easier for people, but you have to do a lot more hooks to access data it seems like.

So the template name is: field--block-content--field-users.html.twig

You're saying the template theme hook would be field__block_content_field_users?

mytheme_preprocess_field__block_content_field_users

?

Comment: Should work, if you use two underscores between block_content and field_users. Don't forget to flush your caches after you added this hook to your theme.

Comment: And yes, twig makes the work for themers easier, given the theme/modules provide the rightful data, which you can assure through preprocessing. ;)

Comment: I can't seem to make this work.

I'm using themename_preprocess_preprocess_field__block_content__field_users and using the name of my theme. 

I didn't realize that you had to do a theme hook for every single field you want to theme. Seems like the .theme file would be enormous after you theme everything. I'll end up having to theme something like 50 fields in this project.

Comment: You don't. You can either add the first mentioned preprocessing to the top level template (as e.g. the block view template, or the node view template), or you do it for some specific fields only as I added within my last edit to the answer.

Comment: re: the email question, This is going to be used as an intranet for a government agency. They want to be able to list users, their names, and their emails in various departments in a block on a page. So I've made a block with a user entity reference and that's what I'm trying to get worked out now. I'm still reading the rest of your answer. Thank you for the tremendous work you've already put into this.

Comment: Ok, maybe another hint: You can also use a views block to create that list. Gives you a lot more flexibility in terms of what data to show and how. But that really is a topic for another question. ;)

Comment: Yeah I'd consider a views block the easiest way, but they need this to be a custom block type that can be put anywhere. So I'm trying to theme a block. Prior to this I've only done Ember/Headless/Services Drupal 8 sites, so doing a stock Drupal site is proving much more difficult than I was expecting.

Comment: A views block can be placed everywhere. I don't get the advantage of creating a block programmatically for this. Anyway, not the rightful place to discuss such kind of application design in a question labeled "iterate through user custom fields in twig". Hope I could get you going for your approach.

Comment: The clients won't have access to views or creating/managing views. They also will need possibly hundreds of these user blocks on various articles and pages to list the authors and/or people in departments and the users will not be the same in each block. There are about 10 custom block types they want in all, so this is very very slow going.

Comment: @JasonGlisson, follow the suggested steps in (1). Render the user entity in a view mode. See the discussion in your last question and the comment by Kevin. So you have three of us giving the same advice.

Comment: @4k4 as much as I appreciate the help, none of your specific comments on this topic have been helpful or thorough. Much like this comment, it's simply not useful or constructive. As much as you are on here, I'd expect more useful answers and less discordant comments. Sorry if that seems ungrateful, but helping others on here requires a little more tact and thoughtfulness. Reminds me of the IT guy that simply says "move!" and remarks on how idiotic the person is for asking for help. Again, sorry if that seems ungrateful, I just didn't see your comments as helpful but rather slightly petulant.

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251859/theming-custom-block-type-have-multiple-paragraph-field#comment308263_251859 for a similar question from today, this is all about entities and view modes.