# Theming custom block type have multiple paragraph field

Tags: 8, theming, blocks, paragraphs

I've created a custom block type includes a paragraph type field and make it multiple. I've configured this block to display it only on the front page. I have a `page--front.html.twig` template in my custom theme. What I want to do in my front page template is looping through the paragraph field to get each field item and theming it in custom HMTL.
 **So what is the correct way to do this?** 
I've tried `block--BLOCKID.html.twig` and try this code.

```
{% for item in content.field_home_page_carousel %}
{{ kint(item.field_home_slide_image) }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I got nothing.

Comment: You need to theme the field inside the paragraph and then the paragraph field itself (the container), not the block.

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with Kevin's comment. Focus on theming the block. 
Activate your theme's debug mode and view the template suggestions for your block. Add a new template and name it as one of the template suggestions, e.g. `block--views-block--more-by-this-author-block-1.html`. 

It may help to duplicate the original block's code and paste into your new twig file, then find a good place to add your for loop. 
Now you can loop through the paragraphs:

```
{% for item in content.field_home_page_carousel %}
    <p>{{ item.field_home_slide_image }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```